# Pandas create a new column based on existing column with chain rule

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have below code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[12, 4, 5, 3, 1],"B":[7, 2, 54, 3, None],"C":[20, 16, 11, 3, 8],"D":[14, 3, None, 2, 6]})
df['A1'] = np.where(df['A'] > 10, 10, np.where(df['A'] < 3, 3, df['A']))
```

While this is okay, I want create the final `dataframe` (i.e. 2nd line of code) using chain rule from the first line. I want to achieve this to increase readability.

Could you please help how can I achieve this?

Comment: Method chaining will not make your code more readable in this case. In my opinion the best option is just to replace the last line with `df['A1'] = df['A'].clip(upper=10,lower=3))` as anky suggested. Using `assign` to chain both lines just makes it harder to read...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [clip](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.clip.html) here:

```
df.assign(A1=df['A'].clip(upper=10,lower=3))
```

---

```
    A     B   C     D  A1
0  12   7.0  20  14.0  10
1   4   2.0  16   3.0   4
2   5  54.0  11   NaN   5
3   3   3.0   3   2.0   3
4   1   NaN   8   6.0   3
```

---

If you really need to do this in one line (note that I dont find this readable)

```
pd.DataFrame({"A":[12, 4, 5, 3, 1],
              "B":[7, 2, 54, 3, None],
              "C":[20, 16, 11, 3, 8],
              "D":[14, 3, None, 2, 6]}).assign(A1=lambda x:x['A'].clip(upper=10,lower=3))
```

Comment: Thanks. But I think it is still taking two lines of code. In the 1st line I am creating `df` and in the second line I am applying your transformation. I actually wanted to have everything in one line

Comment: @BrianSmith One liners are not always readable/maintainable. Remember zen of python: `Simple is better than complex.`

Comment: Why not just `df['A1'] = df['A'].clip(upper=10,lower=3)`? There is no benefit in using `assign` here

Answer (score 1):

You could use np.select() like the following. It makes the conditions and choices very readable.

```
conditions = [df['A'] > 10,
              df['A'] < 3]

choices = [10,3]

df['A2'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default = df['A'])
print(df)

    A     B   C     D  A1
0  12   7.0  20  14.0  10
1   4   2.0  16   3.0   4
2   5  54.0  11   NaN   5
3   3   3.0   3   2.0   3
4   1   NaN   8   6.0   3
```